# Problems validating dinamically added mandatory fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a general script that checks for mandatory fields.
Fields with attribute "mandatory" should be filled always.
The problem is that now I have an input that is mandatory depending on an option selected from other input, so I add/remove the attribute dynamically, but the script isn't detecting it.

Any ideas?
I leave here the function code

Hope you understanded :D

```
function checkMandatory(id){
  var valid = true;
  var selector = "input[mandatory='']";
  if(id){
      selector = "#"+id+" :input[mandatory='']";
  }
  $(selector).each(function(){
      if($(this).val().trim()=="") {
          invalidarInput($(this), "The field is mandatory.");
          valid = false; 
      }
      else {
          $(this).val($(this).val().trim());
          $(this).removeClass("invalido");
          $(this).removeClass("tooltip");
          $(this).removeAttr("ttip");
          $(this).removeAttr("title");
          $(this).unbind("mouseover");
          $(this).unbind("mouseout");   
      }     
  });
return valid;
```

}

Comment: How are you setting the `mandatory` attribute?

Comment: formIdName.inputIdName.setAttributeNode(document.createAttribute('mandatory'))